# I want to know how to propstype to get database like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrayofstring

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577c4b18b1216fd9cb1a2ffc"),
    "username" : "John",
    "todolist" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("577c4b36b1216fd9cb1a2ffd"),
            "newtodo" : {
                "tittle" : "Playing football"
            }
        }
    ],
    "dateAdded" : ISODate("2016-07-06T00:04:40.914Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I write props database like this but it gets error on tittle

```
<p className={styles['author-name']}><FormattedMessage id="by" /> {props.user.username}</p>
      <p className={styles['author-name']}>{props.user.todolist['newtodo.tittle']}</p>
```

And I need to know how to like in Proptypes.shape

```
user: PropTypes.shape({
 username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    todolist:PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        newtodo: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)({
            tittle:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        })
})).isRequired,
```

Please Help me please T-T I am a new in React

Comment: Can you describe better what kind of error are you receiving?

Comment: Actually I can't props(get) tittle value from my database (mongodb). It always probleam that tittle is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it should be:

```
user: PropTypes.shape({
  username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  todolist: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    newtodo: PropTypes.shape({
      tittle: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  })).isRequired
})
```

`newtodo` object should be described with `PropTypes.shape`, not with `Proptypes.objectOf`.

Comment: Thank you but when I test on localhost it is error like this

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'newtodo.tittle' of undefined